# I found a filament that can be used for really precise FDM printing, Who could I hire to create a custom nozzle for it

Tags: print-material, nozzle, pcl

I found this low temperature filament for 3d printing, [Low Temperature Filament 0.5kg 1.75mm, White](https://www.sainsmart.com/products/low-temperature-filament-0-5kg-1-75mm-white)

Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure I can use it for a *really* precise nozzle because it's so runny at normal printing temperature, the thing is, you obviously can't get nozzles at the size I'm taking about, so with that said, who could I hire to make one?

Comment: You can get nozzles down to 0.1mm. You can also get undrilled nozzles. How much lower do you want to go?

Comment: Runniness is pretty much irrelevant.  What matters is how quickly the extruded goop freezes.  Even more important - if your slicer software doesn't "know" about the material characteristics, or the nozzle diameter, you'll get nowhere.

Comment: Further, I see nothing at that site indicating the viscosity is any different from other materials.   Compare:  water melts at 0 Celsius but does not get even "runnier" at the melting point of gallium.

Comment: If you want more precise printing normal PLA/ABS works just fine with a smaller nozzle (like a 0.1mm nozzle), if you want to get even more details you need an SLA printer. Taking low temp filament and using it at high temp will probably just ruin the print and not improve resolution at all (most plastics burn when you overheat them)

Comment: Hi koopa, would you like to edit your question, and specify what size nozzle you are referring to..? If you could make your question a bit more concrete, it could be reopened. As it stands it is a little vague. As Mick states in his comment, there are 0.1 mm nozzles available, why can't you use that size?

Comment: @koopa :D probably nobody can make a custom nozzle for something that you have only in your mind. But there are a lot of drill bits to create for all the sizes available.

Answer (score 6):

You won't need specialized nozzles, you understand the material wrong:

The benefit the properties of this material grant is not super fine prints (which you can get with small nozzles like 0.1 mm already), it is that you can print at super low temperatures. Printing it at standard 200°C will mean, that it won't solidify in the time the printer needs it to, and your walls will all melt down - in worst case it boils off and degrades into useless goop!

You might print PCL onto an already completed print made from a different material with higher printing temperature (if your slicer lets you do that...), like to make a form-shaped piece.

It's low melting point also means you could print parts with it that you *want* to deform under low heat, like a standard shaped flat shin and then just dunk it into 60°C water or put onto a (towel shielded) pocket heater before molding it around the patient, making perfect fits from easy transportable (flat) parts. Or you print "rivets", which you heat, put through the holes in other prints and then flatten with a pair of pliers.

Also, it is one of the cheaper conductive filaments. You might find [this article](http://www.fabbaloo.com/blog/2016/6/24/the-unusual-properties-of-pcl-3d-printer-filament) or the [RepRap Wiki](http://reprap.org/wiki/Polycaprolactone) enlightening.

Beware though: Many printers have a MinTemp set! For example the Ultimaker at 175°C, and you have to force the machine to ignore this with M302.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for some where that could make a custom nozzle and the only place I have found so far that I think might be able to is: https://www.emachineshop.com/

You would need to draw up the design of the nozzle in the software on their web site and see if they could make what you want.

Comment: They probably will demand that you take a massive amount of the nozzles if they do agree to manufacture them. Or charge insane amounts for 1 item.